# ADO.NET Entities, System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, entity-framework

Возникла проблема с запуском приложения, написанном на C# (WPF) с подключением к БД MySql при помощи ADO.NET Entities. Ошибка следующая:

---

```
System.TypeInitializationException не обработано пользовательским кодом
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=Инициализатор типа "System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig" выдал исключение.
  Source=EntityFramework
  TypeName=System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig
  StackTrace:
       в System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()
       в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection..ctor(DbContext context, String nameOrConnectionString)
       в System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
       в AccessToClientsDB.clientdbEntities..ctor() в c:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\...\ClientService\Client\AccessToClientsDB\clientdb.Context.cs:строка 18
       в AccessToClientsDB.AccessToClientsDB..ctor() в c:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\...\ClientService\Client\AccessToClientsDB\AccessToClientsDB.cs:строка 13
       в GUI.MainWindow..ctor() в c:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\...\ClientService\Client\GUI\MainWindow.xaml.cs:строка 26
  InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
       HResult=-2146232062
       Message=Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию
       Source=System.Configuration
       BareMessage=Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию
       Line=0
       StackTrace:
            в System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
            в System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(InternalConfigEventArgs e)
            в System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(String configPath, BaseConfigurationRecord configRecord)
            в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
            в System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
            в System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
            в System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
            в System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
       InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
            HResult=-2146232062
            Message= Неизвестный раздел конфигурации userSettings. (C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\GUI\GUI.vshost.exe_Url_ev1ciwvrswduwtnpzk5phoigckrk3o4m\1.0.0.0\user.config line 3)
            Source=System.Configuration
            BareMessage= Неизвестный раздел конфигурации userSettings.
            Filename=C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\GUI\GUI.vshost.exe_Url_ev1ciwvrswduwtnpzk5phoigckrk3o4m\1.0.0.0\user.config
            Line=3
            StackTrace:
                 в System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
                 в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
                 в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
                 в System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
            InnerException:
```

---

Происходит эта ошибка в классе, написанном средой, подозреваю, что класс этот написан в процессе создания модели. Вот, собственно, его код:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Этот код создан по шаблону.
//
//     Изменения, вносимые в этот файл вручную, могут привести к непредвиденной работе приложения.
//     Изменения, вносимые в этот файл вручную, будут перезаписаны при повторном создании кода.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace AccessToClientsDB
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class clientdbEntities : DbContext
    {
        public clientdbEntities()
            : base("name=clientdbEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<company> company { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<department> department { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<record> record { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<telephone> telephone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Да, модель я добавлял в класс с пространством имен AccessToClientsDB
Исключение выбивает вот на этом этапе:

```
public clientdbEntities()
            : base("name=clientdbEntities")
```

---

### App.config

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <!--<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>-->
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.8.0" newVersion="6.9.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<connectionStrings><add name="clientdbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/clientdb.csdl|res://*/clientdb.ssdl|res://*/clientdb.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=Andrew;password=150468;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=clientdb&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

---

### packages.config

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.ru" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entities" version="6.8.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Web" version="6.9.8" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Единственный момент, который, судя по всем форумам, мог бы смущать - это разные версии EntityFramework, EntityFramework.ru в референсах и в файле пакетов. Но я попробовал поменять в файле на те же, что в референсах и это не помогло исправить ошибку. Еще немного смущает, что в пакетах есть только EntitIES, но нет EntitY, в то время, как в референсах есть Entity.EF6, a EntitIES нет вообще. Не знаю, от чего это зависит, но добавлял пакеты из NuGet, следуя ответу на этот пост: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio
Хотя, если память не обманывает, мог добавить один раз, кроме EntitY пакета еще и EntitIES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам же русским языком написано: в файле `C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\GUI\GUI.vshost.exe_Url_ev1ciwvrswduwtnpzk5phoigckrk3o4m\1.0.0.0\user.config` неизвестный раздел конфигурации `userSettings`.

В .NET система конфигурации устроена таким образом, что если хоть один раздел к конфиге непонятен - падают все попытки обращения к конфигу.

Удалите лишний раздел из этого файла, или же удалите сам файл `user.config` полностью.